# Sign Convention in Field Theory

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, field-theory, conventions

I am working with some field theory and I am at a point where I would like to change my sign convention from $(-,+,+,+)$ to $(+,-,-,-)$. I am worried at some point I will just equations with the wrong sign because I am used to it and just going by memory.

Is there any table with the differences in sign for the "standard" equation (for example Lagrangians, energy-momentum tensor, equation of motion etc?

Comment: I recommend learning how to figure out which convention an equation is using. For example, a Lagrangian has a positive “kinetic” term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: The main rule is that kinetic terms should be positive, cf. above comment by G. Smith.

Example:

- The Lagrangian density for a scalar field is
  $${\cal L}~=~\mp \frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi -{\cal V}(\phi), $$
  with [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)
  $$ \pm\Box\phi~=~{\cal V}^{\prime}(\phi),$$
  if the signature of the Minkowski metric is $(\mp,\pm,\pm,\pm)$, respectively.

  The sign convention for the [stress-energy-momentum (SEM) tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) is
  $$\begin{align} T^{\mu\nu}~=~&\mp \frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\phi)}\partial^{\nu}\phi 
  \pm g^{\mu\nu}{\cal L}
  ~=~\partial^{\mu}\phi\partial^{\nu}\phi \pm g^{\mu\nu}{\cal L}, \cr 
  T_{\mu\nu}~=~&\mp \frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial (\partial^{\mu}\phi)}\partial_{\nu}\phi 
  \pm g_{\mu\nu}{\cal L}
  ~=~\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial_{\nu}\phi \pm g_{\mu\nu}{\cal L}, \end{align}$$
  cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228185/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 1):

Check Appendix E of Burgess & Moore's The Standard Model: A Primer. There is a pretty good collection of results like that there.

PS. Sorry to lose another soldier to the dark side that is the $(+---)$ metric (just kidding)

Comment: Jokes aside, (+−−−) is quite ugly when one wants to check some non relativistic limit, no doubt that the "mostly plus" is a more "natural" choice :D    Here a short list of books listed by convention https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_convention