# On the metric signature and the energy-momentum tensor

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, conventions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Given a Lagrangian $$\mathscr{L} = -\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi - V(\phi),\tag{1}$$ is the metric always with signature $(-, +, +, +)$? It seems to me that This post [Sign Convention in Field Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/589964/) says that the metric is with this signature.

However, when I calculate the energy-momentum tensor, the $00$ component is negative, which is in contradiction to this post [Does metric signature affect the stress energy tensor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228185/).

Note I'm using the definition $$T^{\alpha\beta} = \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial (\partial_\alpha \phi_i)}\frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x_\beta} - \mathscr{L}\eta^{\alpha\beta}\tag{2}$$ but I'm thinking this could depend on the signature of the metric.

Comment: The battle of the metric signature rages on. The best way to see if the metric signature affects things, is to insert a lot of $\eta^{tt}$ terms to keep track of the signature everywhere, and see if they cancel out. IIRC, stress energy tensor has a factor of that, so it should be affected.

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): Where did you get eq. (2) from? It is incompatible with $(−,+,+,+)$.

Comment: @Qmechanic From textbooks that use the $(+,-,-,-)$ convention... So just multiply by $-1$?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.