# The energy-momentum tensor of a scalar field

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In Carroll's *Introduction to General Relativity: Spacetime and Geometry*, I am going to express the components of the energy-momentum tensor of scalar field in three-
vector notation, using the divergence, gradient, curl.

$$
T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{scalar}} = \eta^{\mu\lambda}\eta^{\nu\sigma}\partial_\lambda\varphi \partial_\sigma\varphi - \eta^{\mu\nu} \left(\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\lambda\sigma} \partial_\lambda\varphi \partial_\sigma\varphi + V(\varphi)\right)
$$

---

I think that $\eta^{\mu\lambda}\eta^{\nu\sigma}\partial_\lambda\varphi \partial_\sigma\varphi$ can only be non-zero when $\mu = \lambda = i$ and $\nu = \sigma = j$, so that:

$$
\eta^{ii}\eta^{jj}\partial_i\varphi \partial_j\varphi = \partial_i\varphi\partial_j\varphi \quad(i,j=t,x,y,z)
$$

$$
T^{ij}_{\text{scalar}} = \partial_i\varphi\partial_j\varphi - \eta_{ij}\left\{\frac{1}{2}\left[(\nabla \varphi)^2 - (\partial_t\varphi)^2\right] + V(\varphi)\right\}\quad (i,\ j = t,x,y,z)
$$

---

But I found another solution [here](https://www.general-relativity.net/2020/02/exercise-112-energy-momentum-tensors-of.html):

it says that:

$$
\eta^{\mu\lambda}\eta^{\nu\sigma}\partial_\lambda\varphi \partial_\sigma\varphi = (\eta^{\mu\lambda}\partial_\lambda\varphi) (\eta^{\nu\sigma}\partial_\sigma\varphi) =
\begin{bmatrix}
-\partial_t\varphi \\ \partial_x\varphi \\ \partial_y\varphi \\ \partial_z\varphi
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-\partial_t\varphi & \partial_x\varphi & \partial_y\varphi & \partial_z\varphi
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is a $4 \times 4$ matrix

and then

[image]

---

So that which is right? I am confused with the outer product, is it necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/764942/2451 and links therein.